# Redefine or add Methods to class through decorator. Possible?

Tags: python, decorator

I have class:

```
@custom_decorator
class Creature(objects):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def rise_hands(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'hands rised'
```

I want to define the custom decorator on the top of this class Creature, so that it will redefine the method `rise_hands` or adds new methods.

By the way: how can I redefine the values of `args` or `kwargs`?

**UPDATE:**

The gola is as follow:
I wanna implement an app with decorator for django models. Whatever i define it on the model it will log changes by saving old values and new values of curten fields...

Comment: ...and why would you want to obfuscate your code like this?

Comment: " log changes by saving old values and new values of certain fields".  that's what Django `pre_save` signal  is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't. Do. This.

You have inheritance to do exactly what you're talking about.

```
class FancyCreature( Creature ):

    def __init__(self):
        super( FancyCreature, self ).__init___()

    def rise_hands(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'hands rised'
        super( FancyCreature, self ).rise_hands( *args, **kwargs )

    def new_method( self ):
        print "new method"
```

This is the way you "redefine the method `rise_hands` or adds new methods"

Comment: In Python 3, you can simply use `super().[method]` within a class rather than pass the class name and `self`.

Comment: I know but in my case i Want to redefine behavior of django model save method  or redefine getters of fields to log old and new values every time it changed... or something like this :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can modify arguments in kwargs and args. I don't see anything wrong with doing this in principle

```
>>> def go(func,*args,**kwargs):
...     def g(*args,**kwargs):
...             func(args+(1,),kwargs)
...     return g
... 

>>> @go
... def rise_hands(*args, **kwargs):
...     print args
... 
>>> rise_hands(1)
((1, 1), {})
```